# Is the any possibility of having a Profile model and Customer model in Django e-commerce development?

Tags: python, html, django, authentication, web

I wish to know the possibility of having those two models altogether with other models like Order, OrderItem etc.

I tried running it like in my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True, help_text="Insert your name")
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

Is it possible having such models like the above?

If Yes,

How can I present it in the views.py to authenticate a User(Profile) and at the same create a Customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Your above Model Structure may work well, but in views.py you can use token authentication and at the time of customer creation you can authenticate
if user is exist or not.

Further More You can use `user = request.user` in your views and then

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(user__id=user)
if profile:
 .............
 create your customer here
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely give a feedback when I'm done working on it.